# Nlog from an internal nuget library package

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, nlog

I have written a c# library project and I have added nlog.  I am utilizing logging to file.

I have then created a nuget package for this library using the Nuget Package Explorer with the following files:

```
-lib
    --NLog.config
    --NLog.dll
    --Nlog.xml
    --MyLibrary.dll
    --MyLibrary.dll.config
```

I have then installed this nuget package into a ASP.NET web forms project.  I have installed NLog on this web forms project and have confirmed logging is working correctly for this project.

My problem is that I am not seeing any logging messages for my library project that I have installed via nuget.  The web forms project hierarchy looks like:

```
-WebFormsProject
    --Default.aspx
    --logs.log
    --Default.aspx
    --Nlog.config
    --bin
        ---NLog.dll
        ---Nlog.xml
        ---MyLibrary.dll
        ---WebFormsProject.dll
```

What am I missing to get logging from MyLibrary to work in WebFormsProject?

Comment: Your config does not seem to get copied to your output folder. I'll take a guess and say it has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you made some error in your nlog.config but ...

Please check if the NLog.dll versions you are using are the same (so, the version you build your MyLibrary.dll with and your WebFormsProject).

> Mind that as of NLog version 3.0, the support for dotnetfx20 has been dropped. dotnetfx35 is now needed for using the latest NLog.

If this did not help you, please try another approach to detect what is wrong. For instance, create a simple console application in which you use your newly created nuget package. Do you get your logging to work there?

Comment: The issue was caused by a mismatch in NLog.dll framework versions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to keep in mind, is that if you have an application `Foo` with logging capabilities, and a dll `Bar` with logging capabilities, and `Foo` uses `Bar` (as it usually does with this examples).

```
 + Foo
 |  |   // some console app
 |  |   // references and uses bar
 |   --- Foo.exe
 |   --- NLog.config
 |  
 +--+ Bar
    |   // This is your dll
    |   // it also tries to be cool and log stuff
     --- Bar.dll
     --- NLog.config
```

When you compile and run this, the `Foo` NLog config will be the one used, and the `Bar` config will do nothing (it won't be copied since the `Foo` has one already).